# Strikethrough command in LaTeX

Tags: ulem, strikeout

I am trying to have as strikethrough text using base LaTeX command and up till now there is no solution available except the use of some packages, i.e, `ulem` and `cancel`. Is there any other way to get a strikethrough without using any package? As this is for a learning management system and I don't know how to add packages there, also if I use a command which is not of base LaTeX it gives an error message of undefined sequence. Your help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: The bare latex has no strike through command. So you will have to define one.

Comment: You write about a restricted environment where you can't add packages: Are you sure you are even using LaTeX? Possibly the software uses something like MathJax or KaTeX, which supports LaTeX-like input, but renders the output with a completely different system that has nothing to do with real TeX (and thus does not have LaTeX packages available).

Comment: @moewe yes, the software uses MathJax. Is there any solution in this case?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. MathJax is not LaTeX and MathJax questions are generally off-topic here. Maybe you can get an answer at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mathjax-users or at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax

Comment: the system takes a mathematics input like [latex]\frac{2}{4}\timesx6^{2}[/latex], but I am not aware of all other latex-like commands and hence I am struggling to get my work done.

Comment: If this is HTML-based, have you tried `<del>cross this out</del>`?

Comment: For MathJax maybe https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4473/striking-out-equations could be useful, this needs MathJax extensions to work (which are a bit like LaTeX packages), but maybe these extensions are already available in your system.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a strikethrough macro using no packages. Basically you measure the length of the argument and `\rlap` a `\rule` of the same length.

[image]

You can adjust the height of the `\rule` by changing the `[.5ex]` and adjust its thickness by changing the `{.4pt}`. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\wdth}

\newcommand{\strike}[1]{\settowidth{\wdth}{#1}\rlap{\rule[.5ex]{\wdth}{.4pt}}#1}

\begin{document}

Hello \strike{their} there.

\end{document}
```